# Why won't my button and links naturally fall underneath the input?

Tags: css, html, debugging, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to place `Have an account?`, `Login` button, and `Link A Link B` directly underneath `something something something something`, `Enter Zip Code` input field and `Enter Zip Code` button.

The way I've set up my `Bootstrap` (version 3.3.7) and `HTML`, I'd think that it would've appeared underneath but it's actually displaying the complete opposite of what I expect.  Instead, it's all the way on the left side as per the picture below.

Why's is carrying out this behavior?  If more information is needed please let me know.

[picture of what I'm describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0wEP.png)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-7">
    <form class="pull-right col-12 zipSection">
      <h6 class="pull-right">something something something something</h6>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip Code">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block enterZipCodeButton">Enter Zip Code</button>
    </form>

    <div class="col-12">
      <p class="col-12">Have an account?</p>
      <button type="submit" class="loginButton" onclick="document.location = '/'">Login</button>
      <a href="#">Link A</a>
      <a href="#">Link B</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code into a snippet. Please add any external libraries you used (bootstrap)

Comment: @AniketG I have bootstrap installed via NPM

Comment: I added bootstrap 4 for you. Does that look about right?

Comment: @AniketG I'm changed it to bootstrap 3.3.7 with my above snippet.  It still appears the same way as described originally :(

Comment: Right. Thanks for fixing that

Comment: @AniketG do you possibly have an idea of what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I do. I'm working on an answer right now

Comment: @AniketG ah ok, gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has a class called `pull-right` (which has been renamed to [`float-right`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/) in Bootstrap 4). What that does is forces the div to the far right. Since this is bootstrap, everything else adapts, which means the div which theoretically should be under, gets forced up to the top row, and to the left (since left-alignment is the default). A solution to that is to use the class of `row` from the [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). Every row you want, you make a new div with a class of `row`. This way, they will now be under each other.

However, the `Have an account?` would still be on the left. To fix that, give it a class of `pull-right`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-7">
      <form class="pull-right col-12 zipSection">
        <h6 class="pull-right">something something something something</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zip Code">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block enterZipCodeButton">Enter Zip Code</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 pull-right">
      <p class="col-12">Have an account?</p>
      <button type="submit" class="loginButton" onclick="document.location = '/'">Login</button>
      <a href="#">Link A</a>
      <a href="#">Link B</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```